# How to manage a Webclient.Completed event in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, wpf, webclient

I'm scraping a website using WPF and I'm trying to put requests to a URL foreach string in my List.

Now it looks like the CompletedEvent is not triggered. It just goes back to the loop for the next string in my List. **How can I let it return to the loop AFTER it reached the Completed event?**

```
private void getAdress(double latitude, double longitude)
{
   foreach (string classe in stringList)
   {
        WebClient searchClient= new WebClient();
        searchClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(searchClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        searchClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.theURL.com"));  
    }
}
```

Kind regards,
Niels

Answer (score 1):

You're downloading *asynchronously*. The whole point of asynchrony is that you tell the request to start, along with what you want to happen when it completes... and then you keep going.

If you want to wait until the first request has finished before starting the second one, you should use synchronous calls - but don't do that in a UI thread...

Comment: I understand, but when I change it to "DownloadString(new Uri..." the Break point or MessageBox is still not triggered in the Completed event... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Niels: I don't know whether the events are triggered when you use the synchronous calls - you're expected to use the result of the method call in that case.